# Magento 2 limit max length in Qty field

Tags: magento2, template, addtocart, qty

I wan't to know how to set a max length for the Qty field that is when you click a product (I guess it's product View)
I tried to override the following template and set `maxlength = "4"` but did not work.

```
magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

What template should I override or what item can I modify in the layout to allow just 4 digits in Qty field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a limitation of the html 5 element, not of Magento or your process. That is indeed the location you would need to change, and when I make the edit you described I see it on my front-end when I view source. The problem you're describing is that the input type "number" ignores maxlength.

There are solutions at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome) on regular stack overflow. I wouldn't recommend changing the field to text (although this would work) because it breaks the mobile experience. There are some simple javascript validation techniques described at that link.

Comment: Thank you! as you said it was because of the number type. I used js now it works